# Javascript/Google Apps Script IndexOf issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, indexof

There are a couple of similar queries here about the IndexOf function, but I'm reaching out because although the answers provided have been helpful, none of them have solved the issue.

I have a (very) large 2d array from a spreadsheet of names vs id codes. I read these values in apps script into an array (`rIdr` in the snippet below).

I then build 2x one-dimensional arrays so that I can use IndexOf to search for a name in the first array then use the returned index it to pull out the value from the second array.

```
var keys=[]; var vals=[]; 
  //build key-val lookup arrays
  for (var i = 0; i < rIdr.values.length; i++){ 
    var k = rIdr.values[i][0].toString() 
    keys[i]=k
    var v = rIdr.values[i][1].toString()
    vals[i]=k
  }
```

The name I'm looking for is obtained from a JSON which is populated elsewhere. I iterate over the names in this object, looking for them in my `key` and `val` arrays:

```
  jsonobj.data.forEach(function(value) {
    var idx = keys.indexOf(value.first_names_txt + " " + value.last_name_txt)
    var id = -1;
    if (idx > -1){id = vals[idx]}
    Logger.log(value.first_names_txt + " " + value.last_name_txt + " " + id)
  });
```

I've verified that both the name i'm pulling out of the JSON object as well as the elements of the keys array are String types. I've seen in the object inspector that the keys array is an array of strings (not, for example, an array of array objects).

Try as I might, i can't get IndexOf to return anything other than -1.
Even if I explicitly look for a name which I know is in there (and actually is a copy paste of the name as it's written on the sheet that I'm pulling values from), I still get -1 returned

```
var test
test = keys.indexOf("Joe Bloggs")
```

I'm tearing my hair out here. I don't want to write a separate function to match a name in the keys array, because I'll either need to pass in the full `keys` array as an argument, or make it a global variable - neither of which i want to do for various reasons.

Can anyone help with why IndexOf doesn't work here?

And if this is an issue that won't go away, is there a way to write my own search function which avoids passing large arrays around or declaring them as global variables?

Thanks all in advance

Comment: Can you post a sample of each of your data sources?

Comment: The spreadsheet is just a 2 column list. Name in the first column, id code in the second: <br> Jai Hindley 191310 <br>
Richard Carapaz 3149

Comment: Can you show how the object `rIdr` is constructed?  I would somehow Logger.log(rIdr.values[i][0]), perhaps its not what you think it is.

Comment: sorry comment formatting didn't work. Only other thing is that i'm building the name from the JSON object which stores first name and last name. But as I said, I can't even get a match even with using IndexOf with an explicit value (eg Joe Bloggs above)

Comment: @TheWizEd sure   ```var rIdr   = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(SPREADSHEET_ID,"BCRiderList!A:C");```

Comment: @TheWizEd also I've confirmed that the ``keys`` and ``vals`` arrays are being populated as they should be, and that the data type in the ``keys`` array is String

Comment: Just as a note shouldn't the second `vals[i]=k` be `vals[i]=v`?

Comment: @TheWizEd yes good spot! That'll save me time later. I was actually using ``vals.push(v)`` and ``keys.push(k)``, but changed to this notation to see if it made any difference. Sadly not.

Comment: Can you show some of your jsonobj?

Comment: An example object is [here](https://www.riderhq.com/api/v2/p/events/ev_xg9ckmno/entrants?sort=first_names_txt%20asc&include=q_wg5qq6bgvsy90rh&entrytype_id=et_dv8u152j), but as I said I'm having difficulty matching even with IndexOf("Joe Bloggs") so I don't think the JSON object is the problem

Comment: Are there by any change additional spaces or unusual characters in the spreadsheet values.  Because I can't find anything wrong.

Comment: No - I've even used the ``.trim()`` function when populating the ``keys`` array but that has the same result

Comment: Provide `console.log(JSON.stringify(keys))` showing `Joe Bloggs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description**

I've constructed a spreadsheet sheet using the names from the json data file, randomized the names so they are no longer in alphabetical order and then assigned an id number to each.

[image]

The sample script I've provided lists the id number for the names in the json data file.  Notice I'm working with the original data array.  I don't need to create key value arrays to get the result I want.  And I'm not checking if a name doesn't exist in the data array.

I've truncatd the json data for brevity

**Code.gs**

```
function test_json() {
  try {
    let jdata = {
  "type" : "entrants",
  "data" : [ {
    "type" : "entrant",
    "id" : "en_tdgwjajthr",
    "first_names_txt" : "Archie",
    "last_name_txt" : "White",
    "entrytype" : "et_dv8u152j",
    "answers" : {
      "q_wg5qq6bgvsy90rh" : "Partenza Nude-Espresso RT"
    }
  }, {
.
.
.
.
  }, {
    "type" : "entrant",
    "id" : "en_8uhauoe3jo",
    "first_names_txt" : "Valentijn",
    "last_name_txt" : "Brax",
    "entrytype" : "et_dv8u152j",
    "answers" : {
      "q_wg5qq6bgvsy90rh" : "Dulwich Paragon CC"
    }
  } ],
  "has_more_bool" : false
};
    let values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test").getDataRange().getValues();
    jdata.data.forEach(function(value){
      let key = value.first_names_txt+" "+value.last_name_txt;
      let found = values.find( row => row[0] ===  key );
      console.log("key = "+key+" id = "+found[1]);
    });
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

**Execution log (abbreviated)**

```
10:29:05 AM Notice  Execution started
10:29:06 AM Info    key = Archie White id = 21
10:29:06 AM Info    key = ari panzer id = 15
10:29:06 AM Info    key = Daniel Mulcahy id = 5
10:29:06 AM Info    key = David Streule id = 12
10:29:06 AM Info    key = Dominic Bell id = 10
10:29:06 AM Info    key = Euan Davies id = 14
```

Comment: Thanks @TheWized - this looks very interesting. I'll try the above and report back. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi I get the following error ``7:12:59 AM
Error
TypeError: values.find is not a function`` am I missing a library? this is odd.

Comment: Ignore - got that part working. Now I'm failing to get any matches even tho I know i'm looking for elements that exist. Tried ``ToUpper()`` but still no luck. I'm wondering if the data as stored in the sheet is somehow stored with hidden characters, or in a way that makes matching using ``===`` or ``==`` difficult. This might explain the issue all along (ie that ``IndexOf`` returns -1). On the source spreadsheet I took a data item and found out it's length (using ``=len(A12)`` and it's as expected, so there are no leading/trailing whitespaces.

Comment: The code used to populate the sheet is elsewhere in the project it is: ```function updateBC_riderlookup()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("BCRiderList"); 
  ss.clear();
  var out=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < BC_CATID_MAP.length; i++) { out=out.concat(fetchBC_RiderIDmap(BC_CATID_MAP[i][1],BC_CATID_MAP[i][0] )) }

  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1 , out.length, out[0].length).setValues(out);
}```

Comment: The only way for me to see what the spreadsheet values are is for you to expose the spreadsheet to me.